# Printing escaped characters directly and their relationship with the ASCII table

Tags: c, escaping, ascii

I was looking at the output of an `strace` call when I came across something I had not seen before. The example output was the following (from a call to `recv`, to elaborate):

```
recv(13, "%\0\0\0\23\0\1\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\20\0\5", 37, 0)
```

While other results look like:

```
recv(10, "OK\n", 3, 0)
```

Regardless of what the actual recv intended to convey, I noticed that each of the characters being sent were escaped. I thought that perhaps these escaped characters were related to the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) in a one-to-one fashion (i.e. `\10` being equivalent to `\n`).

So, a quick test like:

```
printf("Before newline \10  After newline);
```

Gives the following result:

```
Before newline   After newline
```

I then tried to just print the value of the character itself in decimal form:

```
printf("Value: %d", '\10');
```

Gives the result:

```
Value: 8
```

So, naturally, since the difference was two I tried:

```
printf("Before newline \12  After newline);
```

Produces:

```
Before newline
After newline
```

---

So, it appears that escaped characters of this format *do* relate to the ascii table with a "less 2" relationship.

- Why is there a difference of two between the ascii table and the escaped character?
- What is the point of this and why does it work in this way?
- Is this just a nuance of `strace`?

Comment: After a little more testing I noticed there was not a "less 2" relationship between the two as mentioned above. The answers below explain this directly.

Answer (score 1):

`strace` is using standard C string notation, in which a backslash followed by digits is an *octal* character code.

10 octal = 8 decimal
12 octal = 10 decimal

Answer (score 1):

The escaped character is not encoded in decimal. It is a one to three digit **octal** number.

C has several forms of character escapes:

1. Backslash and character specifier (i.e. `'\n'`, '`\r'`, etc.)
2. Backslash and 1 to 3 digits (octal specifier, digits must not be 8 or 9. i.e. `'\377'`)
3. Backslash and `x`, then hexadecimal number (i.e. `'\x40'`)
4. Backslash and `u`, then hexadecimal number (Unicode constant)

`10` in octal is `8` in decimal, hence your result. There is not a "less two" relationship, though, because `20` octal is `16` decimal, `30` octal is `24` decimal, etc.